# Svg element changes position when Hovered

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I would like to change svg element scale when I hover it.

My actual problem is when I hover the element, it scales but changes position.

I tried to group my path inside a `g` element but that's also not working.

How can I scale the `path` or `g` element without changing the position?

```js
let svg= document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]
let newpath = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
let newpath2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
let circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
let trainsPathallg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
trainsPathallg.setAttribute('id','trainsPath')
let newpathg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');

newpath.setAttribute('d', 'M0,-10 V10 L10,0 Z');
newpath2.setAttribute('d', 'M0,0 L10,-10 V10 Z');

let progress=50;
let progress2= 300
let progress3= 400
let position = document.getElementById('s3')
let pt1 = position.getPointAtLength(progress);
let pt2 = position.getPointAtLength(progress + 0.1);

let a = (Math.atan2(pt2.y - pt1.y, pt2.x - pt1.x) * 180) / Math.PI;

newpath.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${pt1.x},${pt1.y})rotate(${a})`);


svg.appendChild(trainsPathallg)
trainsPathallg.appendChild(newpathg)
newpathg.appendChild(newpath);
```

```css
#trainsPath > g:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  //transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "0 0 800 300" version = "1.1">
    <path id = "s3" d = "M10.51,27.68c202.42,340.08,200.57-4.6,300,15.67" fill = "none"  stroke = "green" stroke-width = "3"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try transform-origin with `transform-box: fill-box;` & `animation`.

```js
let svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]
let newpath = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
let newpath2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
let circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
let trainsPathallg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
trainsPathallg.setAttribute('id', 'trainsPath')
let newpathg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');

newpath.setAttribute('d', 'M0,-10 V10 L10,0 Z');
newpath2.setAttribute('d', 'M0,0 L10,-10 V10 Z');

let progress = 50;
let progress2 = 300
let progress3 = 400
let position = document.getElementById('s3')
let pt1 = position.getPointAtLength(progress);
let pt2 = position.getPointAtLength(progress + 0.1);

let a = (Math.atan2(pt2.y - pt1.y, pt2.x - pt1.x) * 180) / Math.PI;

newpath.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${pt1.x},${pt1.y})rotate(${a})`);


svg.appendChild(trainsPathallg)
trainsPathallg.appendChild(newpathg)
newpathg.appendChild(newpath);
```

```css
#trainsPath>g:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}

#trainsPath g {
  transition: transform .2s;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 800 300" version="1.1">
    <path id = "s3" d = "M10.51,27.68c202.42,340.08,200.57-4.6,300,15.67" fill = "none"  stroke = "green" stroke-width = "3"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: In my real app I render arrows dynamically, so I can't hard code transform-origin value. I'm looking to find a way to find arrow middle `x` and `y` from translate attribute

Comment: Any Idea why when I use `#trainsPath>g>path:hover` is CSS it does translate the path when hover ( like initial problem ) ?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want transform-origin and transform-box.

```js
let svg= document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]
let newpath = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
let newpath2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
let circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
let trainsPathallg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
trainsPathallg.setAttribute('id','trainsPath')
let newpathg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');

newpath.setAttribute('d', 'M0,-10 V10 L10,0 Z');
newpath2.setAttribute('d', 'M0,0 L10,-10 V10 Z');

let progress=50;
let progress2= 300
let progress3= 400
let position = document.getElementById('s3')
let pt1 = position.getPointAtLength(progress);
let pt2 = position.getPointAtLength(progress + 0.1);

let a = (Math.atan2(pt2.y - pt1.y, pt2.x - pt1.x) * 180) / Math.PI;

newpath.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${pt1.x},${pt1.y})rotate(${a})`);


svg.appendChild(trainsPathallg)
trainsPathallg.appendChild(newpathg)
newpathg.appendChild(newpath);
```

```css
#trainsPath > g:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "0 0 800 300" version = "1.1">
   <path id = "s3" d = "M10.51,27.68c202.42,340.08,200.57-4.6,300,15.67" fill = "none"  stroke = "green" stroke-width = "3"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this CSS code:

```
<style>
    transform: scale(1.5);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-box: fill-box;
</style>
```

Comment: My app redender arrow dynamically I can't hard code origin values